# Intellij structural search: find field and corresponding getter (to migrate an annotation)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

I am trying to migrate an annotation from a field to it's getter using Intellij's fancy structural replace:

From:

```
class MyClass {
   @SomeAnnotation
   private final double a;
   @SomeAnnotation
   private final double b;

   public double getA() {
       return a;
   }

   public double getB() {
      return b;
   }
}
```

To:

```
class MyClass {
   private final double a;
   private final double b;

   @SomeAnnotation
   public double getA() {
       return a;
   }

   @SomeAnnotation
   public double getB() {
      return b;
   }
}
```

I am most of the way there with:

Search template:

```
class $Class$ {
    @SomeAnnotation
    private final $type$ $fieldName$;

    public $type$ $getter$() {
        return $value$;
    }
}
```

Replace template:

```
class $Class$ {
    private final $type$ $fieldName$;

    @SomeAnnotation
    public $type$ $getter$() {
        return $value$;
    }
}
```

There is also a filter on getter that matches `get.*`, and a Script on the whole template to try to make sure we find the matching getter:

```
if (getter.name.toLowerCase().contains(fieldName.get(0).name.toLowerCase())) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

The problem is that this only matches the first getter, and the script doesn't get a chance to try with all of them.

Any way I could alter my search for this to work?

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert on IntelliJ Structural Search, but I suspect this is too much for it (though you could always just run it over and over again until it stops changing things).

I think this is a job for a tool like [OpenRewrite](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite) or similar, which allows you to read the AST and generate new code.

Comment: Running it over and over won't work, as it only ever matches the first getter (so if I remove the script, all annotations end up on the first getter). 
OpenRewrite looks cool though!